# Convergence of definite integral

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm struggling with improper integrals in the context of definite integrals that become undefined within the limits of integration (I believe that this is Type II). 
For example, $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^2 dx}{x-1}$$
I've tried to utilize the comparison test, but I am having trouble determining a suitable function that is larger than this function to compare its convergence. Is there a set of rules I should be aware of when generating corresponding integers to test for convergence? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{x^2}{x-1}=x+1+\frac{1}{x-1}$